# Creating buttons in a Javascript constructor

Tags: javascript

i'm pretty new at JavaScript and pretty stumped at why my buttons in the constructor are not appearing in a table i've created. Can anyone tell me if I can create buttons in a constructor or do I need a separate function to create the button dynamically

```
         <!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html">
  <title>Client Side Shopping Basket</title>
  <meta name="author" content="Justin Butterworth">
  <link href="basket.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" media="screen" />
</head>

<body>
<div id="container">
    <header id="title">
        <h1>Products</h1>
    </header>
    <div id="output">
        <table border="1" id="tProducts">
            <tr>
                <th>Name</th>
                <th>Description</th>
                <th>Quantity</th>
                <th>Price</th>
                <th>Gender</th>
            </tr>
        </table>
    </div>
    <br /><br />
    <header id="title">
        <h1>Shopping Basket</h1>
    </header>
    <div id="totals">
        <table border="1">
            <tbody>
                <!-- tax + subtotal -->
                <tr class="netcost">
                    <td class="light">Net Total:</td>
                    <td colspan="2" class="light"></td>
                    <td>&nbsp;</td>
                    <td>&nbsp;</td>
                </tr>
                <tr class="totalcost">
                    <td class="light">Total:</td>
                    <td colspan="2">&nbsp;</td>
                    <td colspan="2"><span class="thick">£225.45</span></td>
                </tr>

                <!-- checkout btn -->
                <tr class="checkoutrow">
                    <td colspan="5" class="checkout"><button id="submitbtn">Checkout Now!</button></td>
                </tr>
            </tbody>
        </table>
    </div>
</div>
<p id="test"></p>

<script>
var productList=[]; //where product objects are to be held
var basket=[];

//constructor
function Products(name, description, quantity, price, gender) 
{ 
    var obj = this; // a reference to this object

    this.name = name;
    this.description = description;
    this.quantity = quantity;
    this.price = price.toFixed(2);
    this.gender = gender;

    this.getName = function() {
        return this.name
    };

    this.getPrice = function() {
        return '\u00A3' + this.price;
    };
}

//instantiate new products 
var shorts = new Products('Shorts', 'Stone Wash Demin Shorts', 20, 25.90, 'F');
var bag = new Products('Bag', 'Leather Shoulder Bag', 4, 50.45, 'F');
var blouse = new Products('Blouse', 'Vintage Blue Silk Polka Dot Blouse', 8, 45.99, 'F');
var boots = new Products('Boots', 'Soft Leather Brown Ankle Boots', 3, 65.35, 'F');
var belts = new Products('Belts', 'Woven Finish Fashion Belt', 15, 21.99, 'F');
var shirt = new Products('Shirt', 'Jacquard Pattern Wrangler Western Shirt', 19, 34.87, 'M');
var shoes = new Products('Shoes', 'Suede Ankle Boots', 6, 55.00, 'M');
var trousers = new Products('Trousers', 'Izod Peach Chinos', 23, 31.75, 'M');
var belt = new Products('Belt', 'Suede Casual Belt', 4, 22.98, 'M');
var hat = new Products('Hat', 'Trilby Style Brown Woven Fix', 2, 67.80, 'M');

//add objects to an array
productList.push(shorts, bag, blouse, boots, belts, shirt, shoes, trousers, belt, hat);


//function to display full product list
function displayProducts(tProducts)
{   
    var table = document.getElementById('tProducts'); // reference to the table to add rows to
        for (var i = 0; i < tProducts.length; ++i) // iterate through the array for each of the products
    {   
        var product = tProducts[i];  // keep a reference to each individual product
        var row = document.createElement('tr'); // create a row element to append cells to
        var properties = ['name', 'description', 'quantity', 'price', 'gender']; // properties of the array elements

        for (var j = 0; j < properties.length; ++j) // append each one of them to the row in question, in order
        {   
            var cell = document.createElement('td'); // create new data cell for names
            cell.innerHTML = product[properties[j]]; // set name of property using bracket notation (properties[j] is a string, which can be used to access properties of product)
            row.appendChild(cell); // add to end of the row
        }
        row.appendChild(createBtn());
        table.appendChild(row); // add new row to table
    }
};

function createBtn() {
        var btn   = document.createElement('input');
        btn.type  = 'button'
        btn.name  = name;
        btn.value = 'Add';
        btn.onclick = function() {
            return obj.getPrice();
        };
    return btn;
};

displayProducts(productList);
</script>

</body>
</html>
```

Okay.. I've created to button elements but how can I update the name of the button to the products name? It's a scope problem which is one aspect i'm still trying to get my head around in JavaScript.

@RobG Also added all the code

Comment: How/where is the `.createBtn()` function being called? And `document.write()` is probably the wrong approach.

Comment: If you are calling *instance.createBtn* after the load event has been dispatched, *document.write* is going to clear the entire document of all content, then insert a single button.

Comment: The *createBtn* function should use DOM methods to create the button and should either return the newly created button so it can be added to the right place in the document, or it should take a DOM element as an argument that the button will be added to. Oh, and doing this inside a constructor doesn't make sense. *this.getPrice* will reference the *getPrice* property of the button, not of the *products* instance.

Comment: Thank you, I'm just playing around with the code... My objective is to add more methods to add data to another array and display it in a table

Comment: i'm still learning  :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Some tips:

- Object constructors preferably with capital first letter (convention)
- Object methods when possible in prototype (makes each object lighter using shared methods)
- `innerHTML` is a string method and is heavier than DOM tree manipulation. It's ok to use, but prefer DOM manip, or at least be consistent and choose one of both.

```
function Product(name, description, quantity, price, gender) { 
    this.name = name;
    this.description = description;
    this.quantity = quantity;
    this.price = price;
    this.gender = gender;
}
Product.prototype.getPrice = function() {
    // dummy output, just to test
    alert(this.name + ' ' + '£' + this.price);
};
Product.prototype.createBtn = function(parent) {
    var input = document.createElement('input');
    input.id = this.name;
    input.value = 'Add';
    input.type = 'button';
    input.addEventListener ? input.addEventListener('click', this.getPrice.bind(this), false): 
       input.attachEvent('onclick',this.getPrice.bind(this));
    parent.appendChild(input);
};
// instantiate & append to body
var x = new Product('product-1','some descr',5,25,'male');
x.createBtn(document.body);
```

**Note:** the `function().bind()` construct is really useful for binding object scope even after bound to a DOM element but only works from IE9+ . To support legacy browser, see RobG's answer (use methods inside object with private variables & not prototype).

Answer (score 0):

I tried your function with:

```
var p = new products("name", "des", 1, 1, "");
p.createBtn();
```

and it worked fine for me.

Answer (score 0):

It doesn't make sense to do what you are doing in a constructor. The button created by the instance has no relationship at all to the object that created it. It would be better to use a product ID or similar and have the data in a data store (e.g. another object).

It is convention to give constructors a name starting with a capital letter, and also they creat a single instance so give it a singular name, e.g.:

```
function Product(name, description, quantity, price, gender) { 

  // Keep a reference to the instance in a closure
  var obj = this;

  this.name = name;
  this.description = description;
  this.quantity = quantity;
  this.price = price;
  this.gender = gender;
  this.getPrice = function() {
    return this.name + ' ' + '£' + this.price;
  };

  // Within the function, use obj to reference the instance, not this
  this.createBtn = function() {
    var btn   = document.createElement('input');
    btn.type  = 'button'
    btn.name  = obj.name;
    btn.value = 'Add';
    btn.onclick = function() {

      // Important to use obj here to ensure getPrice is called 
      // with expected value for this
      // return obj.getPrice();  

      // for testing
      return console.log( obj.getPrice() );
    };
    return btn;
  };
}
```

Just a test be if markup:

```
<div id="basket"></div>
```

Now you can do:

```
var foo = new Product('foo', 'A large Foo', 6, 2.5, 'Pan');
document.getElementById('basket').appendChild(foo.createBtn());
```

However, clicking the button returns the price to nowhere so I've added the debug line.

Comment: Where do I add the button when the rows are created in the displayTable function? Thanks

Comment: I guess after `cell.innerHTML = product[properties[j]];`, use `cell.appendChild(foo.createBtn());`

Answer (score 0):

Should be more like:

```
var doc = document, bod = document.body, Product;
function E(id){
  return doc.getElementById(id);
}
function C(t){
  return doc.createElement(t);
}
(function(){
// add other vars, functions and so forth to remain inside scope
Product = function(name, description, quantity, price, gender){
  var productContext = this;
  this.name = name; this.description = description; this.quantity = quantity;
  this.price = price.toFixed(2); this.gender = gender; 
  this.getPrice = function(){
    return this.name+' \u00A3'+this.price;
  }
  this.createButton = function(where){
    var btn = C('input');
    btn.type = 'button'; btn.id = this.name; // will be a problem if there's a space
    btn.value = 'Add';
    btn.onclick = function(ev){
      var e = ev || event; // event Object to var e
      /* put code here
         can use var productContext to refer to Product this
         this refers to btn in here */
    }
    where.appendChild(btn);
  }
}
})();
```

Using your code on another external JavaScript page:

```
var pre = onload;
onload = function(){
if(pre)pre(); // executes old onload and preserves scope
function whatever(){
  // normal indentation here
}
var prod = new Product('SomeName', 'Description Here', 10, 12.5, 'male');
prod.createButton(E('someId'));
}
```